# Pieces of music playing when Eastwood attempts to kill the radio officer

Tags: soundtrack, where-eagles-dare

In the classic Maclean flick, *Where Eagles Dare*, what are the pieces of music that the radio operator is listening to before/when Clint Eastwood tries to kill him with a knife? I've been informed that one of them was composed by a Jewish composer and am rather sceptical of the claim.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [fan site](http://www.whereeaglesdare.com/movie/index.php?page=soundtrack), the soundtrack has a 2 minute 5 second clip of *Fox Trot* which is "the piece that the German Radio operator listens to just before he switches [off] the radio".

[Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004TZDBIK) is a previewable soundtrack album in which nothing is listed as *Fox Trot*, but track 7 is "Death Of Radio Engineer And Helicopter Pilot" which sounds like score, not something a character would listen to.

Comment: Actually, the linked fan site names it (only one?) as *Beguine* (1:13) (When Schaffer sneaks up the stairs to the radio room, you can hear the German Radio Operator listening to music. It is this piece that you hear. It is played in waltz time and it sounds like a piece from fourties. Just the period when this movie is to take place.) Assuming that Ron Goodwin composed it, there does not appear to be any Jewish connection. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Tune is Charmaine. Written in 1926 by Erno Rapee and Lew Pollack. Both American composers. And yes Lew Pollack was Jewish.